# Excel VBA - Work with Subgroup of Array

Tags: arrays, loops, excel, vba

I have a 1-dimensional array with 1000 entries. I would like to loop through parts of this array and apply calculate an average on that subgroup. What I have done so far looks like this:

```
        Temp = Array(myArray)

        Temp_Range = Application.Index(Temp, Evaluate("Row(1:10)"))

        Average(i) = Application.Average(Temp_Range)
```

By this I can calculate the average of the first 10 rows. This is however not dynamic at all, and I was wondering if there is another way of working with subgroups of this array (so that I can eventually loop through them)?

Thanks for your help, I just can't figure this one out...

**Update:**
I tried your code here with St.Dev (not average). It works! So thanks very much. However, the code is really slow. Would there be a way of making it faster?

Here the loop: Return is an array of 1000 returns. I aim to calculate the standard deviation of one year of daily return data.

```
    For i = 2 To n

    If Year(Dates(i)) > Year(Dates(i - 1)) Then

        Test = Application.Index(Return, Evaluate("Row(" & C & ":" & (i - 2) & ")"))

        Vola(M) = Application.StDev(Test) * Sqr(252)

        M = M + 1
        C = i - 1

    Else

        Test = Application.Index(Return, Evaluate("Row(" & C & ":" & (i - 1) & ")"))

        On Error Resume Next
        Vola(M) = Application.StDev(Test) * Sqr(252)

    End If

Next i
```

Comment: Subgroups of? Every ten rows? every row between 2 rows that contain a specific value/word. User entered range. Average of rows that contain specific value? The more we know the more we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing any more about *how* you're looping through these, you could:

```
Dim frstRow as Long, lstRow as Long

'within your loop, assign the values to frstRow, lstRow

Temp_Range = Application.Index(Temp, Evaluate("Row(" & frstRow & ":" & lstRow &")"))
```

Comment: Your code does work! Thanks alot! Can you have a look at my update?

Comment: Please consider accepting this as the "solution" if it is working for you.  As for the speed/slowness, what is the value of `n`?  If you are performing any operation many thousands of times, it will take some time to process this loop.

Comment: N is not that big. I wrote the code (completely) differently before (I mean with a different concept) and it ran less than 1 sec. Now it takes about 3 seconds. Not that much of course, don't worry, I was just wondering if there is an even more efficient solution =)